# javascript extension redirect redirectURL failure

Tags: javascript

I think I'm making a stupid mistake that I,unfortunately,cannot notice.
The below code works fine if redirectUrl is 'something' but is saying "missing } after property list" when I try to add a variable/string to that 'something'.My conclusion is,adding something to redirectUrl is not simply 'something' + variable.How do I fix this issue?

```
var host = "hypertexttransmissionprotocol://site.com/*"
function funchere(requestDetails) {
return {
       redirectUrl: 'something' +variable+ 'something'; 
};
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    funchere,
    {urls:[host], types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]},
    ["blocking"]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing semicolon at the end:

```
return {
       redirectUrl: 'something' + variable + 'something'
};
```

Comment: you still need to remove semicolon, it is not proper JSON format if you keep it.

Comment: Oh,a mistake on my end.Forgot to add a plus sign.It is working!Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!  You can mark this as a correct answer :)